# Can we write a case study by referring our previous work instead of re-writing?

Tags: publications, writing, extended-paper

I have been writing some papers for a while in computer science. Now when I look at my case study, I found it too long to be as a section in a paper. Instead, i want to write a separate paper for the case study.
I don't want to re-phrase the introduction, related work, the algorithms and our proposed methods etc.
Will it be OR is it permissible to write a pure case study only and referring my previous papers for the details. Of course, i will add some introduction to just let the user know what is going on in this paper and if the reader is interested can refer to other papers. what I have in mind is the flow of paper be like

Abstract

Introduction

Case study parameters

Case study Setup

Case Study working

Case Study Result

Conclusion

also if a reliable source is provided will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can publish a case study as a (conference) paper and your proposed structure looks reasonable, albeit I have a few comments.

> I don't want to re-phrase the introduction, related work, the algorithms and our proposed methods etc.

You'll clearly need a new introduction. You'll possibly also need a new related work section too (which is missing from your proposed flow). The algorithms and proposed methods can be copy-and-pasted, as long as they are attributed to your previous work, but you might need to revise some of the introductory material to those algorithms and methods.

Since you're in computer science, you have another option: Publish the complete work as a journal paper, rather than a conference paper.

Comment: What i meant is that, is it acceptable to write half or one page paragraph for the intro and go straight into the case study. As the rest are already discribed earlier in my previous paper which i can refer in this case study.

Comment: You just need to ensure that the case-study paper is self-contained.